# Out of memory error using MATLAB R2012a generating a 2 MB vector

Tags: matlab, memory

When I try to execute the following command in MATLAB:

```
zero_vector = zeros( 128*128*16 );
```

I get the following message:

```
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

I don't have the memory command available on my Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.5 platform. In any case, I expect that I should be able to create a 2 MB vector of zeros in MATLAB 7.14.0.739 (R2012a). Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will generate a big square matrix.

To generate a vector, do that:

```
zero_vector = zeros( 128*128*16 , 1 );
```

Comment: @Fares also depending on what you want to store in the vector, you may want to consider using `sparse` matrix.

Answer (score 6):

You're generating a square matrix.

Try:

```
zero_vector = zeros(128*128*16,1)
```